# Where to keep and how to get version of qooxdoo app?

Tags: frameworks, qooxdoo

I have a version of qooxdoo app in `Manifest` file and would like to show it up in `About` window for example or at bottom panel/bar. But I don't know how to get the version from config files. I search for classes in API but didn't find. Seems like to hard code it in code of app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the Qooxdoo version from the environment: `qx.core.Environment.get("qx.version")`

Or information about all the libraries (including your application) with `qx.core.Environment.get("qx.libraryInfoMap");`

EG if your app has a namespace of "myapp", you can get the version with `qx.core.Environment.get("qx.libraryInfoMap")["myapp"].version`